# UISearchController – Search result show different records

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisearchcontroller

When i type "stefanik" in searchbar the result is one record (but different look), when i tap on this, is the right record, see screenshots.
I think problem is in these methods, but i cant find the problem.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (self.searchController.active)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (self.searchController.active)
    {
        return [self.filteredList count];
    }
    else
    {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }

}
```

Have you seen this problem before?
Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `NSFetchedResultsController` apply an `NSPredicate` to filter the records for example

```
if (self.searchController.active) {
    self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind){
        return [[(Airport *)obj name] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound;
    }];
} else {
    self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = nil
}
// reload data
```

This is more efficient than filtering in code into an extra array

Comment: Hi thx. for help, i found the problem, problem was in 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath